# Element not centered properly

Tags: html, css

All I want to do is align both social media links and the copyright on the center of the page. I have tried using the center alignment trick with margin with 0px auto. That does not seem to work. If you wouldn't mind explaining what it is I am doing wrong that would be great. Thanks!
***CSS:***

```
.social-slide {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 30px;
    float: right;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}
.social-slide:hover {
    background-position: 0px -30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
} 


.twitter-hover {
    background-image: url(
        'http://ktmf.images.worldnow.com/images/2708288_G.png'
    );
}
.facebook-hover {
    background-image: url(
        'http://ktmf.images.worldnow.com/images/2708289_G.png'
    );
}

.center {
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank">
            <span class="twitter-hover social-slide"></span>
        </a>

        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/" target="_blank"> 
            <span class="facebook-hover social-slide"> </span>
        </a>
        <br>
        <br>

        <p>© 2013 </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you wouldn't mind explaining what it is I am doing wrong that
>   would be great.

What is happening is that you are centering the div, but by default it will fill its parent container, which in this case is your `<body>` element. So, doing `margin: 0px auto` on that `<div>` will center the div, but it will behave as though it is set to `width:100%`

Also, to prevent layout issues you should clear your `float:right` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a width on that div for that method to work properly.

For all:

```
.center {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or just that one (without extra class/ID)

```
body > .center {
    width: 800px;
}
```

Though I would suggest an ID of 'container' or similar, then assign a width to that (`#container`)

Answer (score 0):

You can write `text-align:center;` in you class `.center`. This may work for you.

Comment: This will work, because it will center the two `<a>` elements within the div, which are set to `display:inline`. However, I think he wants to center the container `<div>` instead of the two `<a>` elements.